# C# Entity Framework not updating or refreshing after Commit (SaveChanges)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

We found a bug in our System. We are using Entity Framework 6. It seems, that the EF is not updating or refrehing after a commit (saveChanges()).

Process:

Add a item to the EntityFramework :

```
ShareRefund e = new ShareRefund()
        {
            Client_id = message.Client_id,
            SubcriptionCertificate_id = suct.Id,
            DTAUS = message.DTAUS,
            Accounting_id = deposit.Id,
            Amount = maxRefund,
            Created_id = message.Created_id,
            Employee = _context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Id == message.Employee_id),
            SubscriptionCertificate = suct,
            Accounting = deposit,
            Client = _context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == message.Client_id),
            Login = _context.Logins.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == message.Created_id),
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            CustomId = suct.CustomId,
            Employee_id = message.Employee_id,
            NoInterest = message.NoInterest,
            RefundDate = message.RefundDate

        };

        _context.ShareRefunds.Add(e);
```

After this we call `_context.Commit();`
Its defined as see below:

```
public void Commit() {
        try {
            this.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch () {
            some code here
        }
    }
```

Before finishing the method we step into another class and use a new instance of `_context`.
There we want to get the added item `e` by using this:

```
int refundedId = shareRefundId.First();
ShareRefund refund = context.ShareRefunds
   .Where(t => t.Client_id == client.Id)
       .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == refundedId);
```

When I step into it with a debugger and take a look into my database at this point, the entry with the given id exists in my database. But the `_context` always returns null.

Are there any known issues or solutions to refresh the context correctly after a commit?

---

This is my Constructor where  a new instance of the `context is created:

```
private readonly Context context;

    #region constructor/destructor

    public ReportingManager() {
        context = new Context("Context");
        workingDirectory = String.Format(workingDirectory, InstanceConfiguration.DefaultAppFolder);

        configDirectory = workingDirectory + @"configs\";
        templateDirectory = workingDirectory + @"templates\";
        temporaryDirectory = workingDirectory + @"temp\";
    }

    public ReportingManager(string connectionString, string appFolder) {
        context = new Context(connectionString);
        workingDirectory = String.Format(workingDirectory, appFolder);

        configDirectory = workingDirectory + @"configs\";
        templateDirectory = workingDirectory + @"templates\";
        temporaryDirectory = workingDirectory + @"temp\";
    }
```

Comment: Please write in post  your _context instance define code. sample : DbEntitiesName _context = new DbEntitiesName();

Comment: Usually, an empty, exception-eating `catch` statement makes it hard/impossible to write stable code.

Comment: I'd like to see an example where I can track all values by reading the code.  Did you forget to put the Id into `shareRefundId`? Are you using the same Client_id?

Comment: There is some code in it where exceptions are handled. While call 'SaveChanges()' nothing is catched in the catch-block.

Comment: No, it's all correct. The id exists and the client_id too

Comment: @FlorianQo we can't still see how `_context` initilaized.

Comment: What SQL is your FirstOrDefault(...) generating? BTW, you don't need a Where and a condition within FirstOrDefault -- you can combine them and dump the where.

Comment: Yes, I know. It was writting by another employee. Thanks.

Comment: the Context is initialized in the constructor. 'context = new Context("Context")'